# Zend 2 with Doctrine 2 - setting credential callable manually

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to authenticate a user using Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine 2.

How do I set or change the credentialCallable option in the controller's action method.

```
$adapter = $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter();
// how to set credentialCallable option here
$adapter->setIdentityValue($data['username']);
$adapter->setCredentialValue($data['password']);
$result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();
```

By the way, I know how to set it in config file. (see documentation https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/authentication.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$options = new \DoctrineModule\Options\Authentication;
$options->setCredentialCallable(function (User $user, $passwordGiven) { //body });
$adapter->setOptions($options);
```